# Models of Linear Logic

Tags: logic, reference-request, linear-logic

I am looking for an introduction to the model theory of Linear Logic. Can you recommend any clear introductions?

I am particularly interested in those models that regard coherence spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came across this question. Maybe it's a bit late but I can suggest some references as well.

- *Linear Logic : its syntax and semantics (Part 2.2.3)*, J.Y Girard.
- *Introduction to linear logic and ludics, Part I (Part 6)*, P.L Curien.
- *On the meaning of logical rules I : syntax vs semantics (Part D)*, J.Y Girard

And indeed, *Proof and Types* as *Rob Arthan* suggested.

If you're also interested in the relation between Linear Logic and Game Semantics, you can check :

- *Semantics of Interaction*, S. Abramsky.

Answer (score 2):

Clarity seems to be a rare commodity in the literature on linear logic. However, Girard's [Proofs and Types](http://www.paultaylor.eu/stable/Proofs+Types.html) is the place to start for coherence spaces.